# Redirecting to correct secure URI whilst invisibly pathing to a sub folder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I am trying to write the correct rewrites in my .htaccess file in order to have all non-www. and https:// requests redirect to https://www.example.com whilst also having the domain invisibly redirect to a subdirectory "build" as the base directory.

So if the index.html is in home/var/www/example.com/public_html/build/index.html the URI path still needs to be https://www.example.com/index.html.

I do have all but the non-www. part redirecting correctly, just cannot get that part working also.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /build

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/build/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /build/$1 [L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What URL is not working with these rules in place and what is exact error? Test in a new browser to avoid old cache.

Comment: Hi. I am always testing in a new browser as you state. The URL not working is, https://example.com (without www.) it is not redirecting to https:// www example com.

Comment: Is this .htaccess inside `/build/` ?

Comment: Not it is currently within the route "public_html".

Comment: What is your Apache version?